# How can I force a bundle install on Openshift?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openshift

So how exactly does one commit .openshift/markers/force_clean_build to force a clean bundle? As per results from git push  below...

remote: NOTE: You can commit .openshift/markers/force_clean_build to force a clean bundle

remote: NOTE: Skipping 'bundle install' because Gemfile is not modified.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you just need to add an empty `force_clean_build` file in the `.openshift/markers` directory, add/commit it to git, and push that:

```
cd app_name
touch .openshift/markers/force_clean_build
git add .openshift/markers/force_clean_build
git commit -m "Force a clean bundle"
```

See http://atodorov.org/blog/2012/02/18/how-to-update-dependencies-on-openshift/ for an overview of this.

Comment: Thanks Dylan. But do I type that stuff locally on my mac or  on the remote sever via ssh?

Comment: Locally, in the repo that you're working with. So once that file's committed, then next time you `git push` the server will see that new file and know to force bundle to run.

Comment: OK, then later, how do you turn force_clean_build off?

Comment: Based on that blog post, I would assume you would just `git rm .openshift/markers/force_clean_build`, commit, push again, and it'll then see that you no longer have that file.